# MapView.preLoad() does what exactly?

Tags: android, android-mapview, preload

What does the Android MapView.preLoad() method really do? "The API states Preload the tiles at the map's current center". What does this mean and can I somehow use it to speed up loading of the map in my MapView?

Best regards

P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the actual map graphics and information for the map is loaded from google maps. You can't use this to **really** speed up loading (the actual load time in the end will be about the same), but you might be able to do loading of data BEFORE the user decides to go into your map view. Which would of course help a lot, but it all depends in your application and how the user interacts with it.

Comment: Ok, so for example if the MapView is only shown under certain circumstances I can start loading data directly and then when MapView is shown it may already be loaded? If that's the case this method gives noting extra if the MapView is always shown directly when the Activity holding the MapView is shown?

Comment: What radius does this work out of? Does it just pull the immediate surrounding tiles at the current zoom level, or all zoom levels... ? You say you can preload before the user goes to the Map View, but can does the MapView actually get centered to a location if it's not in the foreground?